# How do you concatenate strings inside of a CONTAINS in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

SQL Server 2008 is telling me that it doesn't like the "+" in the CONTAINS.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblImportTitles
  (
   ImportTitleGUID,
   UserGUID,
   TitleName,
   TitleGUID
  )
  SELECT
   ImportTitleGUID = T.Item.value('@ImportTitleGUID', 'uniqueidentifier'),
   UserGUID = T.Item.value('@UserGUID', 'uniqueidentifier'),
   TitleName = T.Item.value('@TitleName', 'varchar(255)'),

   TitleGUID = 
   CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT TOP(2) COUNT(TitleGUID) FROM dbo.tblTitles WHERE CONTAINS(Title, '''' + T.Item.value('@TitleName', 'varchar(255)') + '''')) = 1
    THEN (SELECT TitleGUID FROM dbo.tblTitles WHERE CONTAINS(Title,'''' + T.Item.value('@TitleName', 'varchar(255)') + ''''))
    ELSE NULL
   END  

  FROM @ImportTitlesInsertXml.nodes('BatchTitles/BTitle') AS T(Item)
```

**Update**

I'v decided to move this to a scalar function.
It was a lot easier to handle the code that way.

Answer (score 1):

use QUOTENAME(@VARIABLE,'''') the + is not your problem.