# FTS Contains string concatenate

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, concatenation, contains

im working on FTS and has been stuck in a problem.With respect to . [How do you concatenate strings inside of a CONTAINS in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805288/how-do-you-concatenate-strings-inside-of-a-contains-in-sql-server-2008)

im trying to use Contains function of FTS
and i need to pass search string either as concatenated string or return string from a scalar function. but both options are not available in FTS.

it does not allow to concatenate search string inside "`Contains`" Clause

```
select top 10 * from dbo.staging_table with (nolock)
where contains(text,N'"pakistan"'+'" Lahore"')
```

select top 10 * from dbo.staging_table with (nolock)
where contains(text,(select from dbo.getcityList()))

second option is again unavailable as it is expecting a string argument.
Im using this query in a view so i cant declare any variable :(
Please help me in resolving this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use table-valued function instead of a view.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fTestFTS (@str NVARCHAR(4000))
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN (
    select top 10 *
    from dbo.staging_table
    where contains(*, @str)
)

SELECT * FROM dbo.fTestFTS(N'"pakistan"' + ' &' + '" Lahore"')
```

Note the ampersand in search string.